# Reversing a Subrouter in Gorilla / Mux

Tags: go, gorilla

I would like to get the path for a named subroute but my code below does not work. When I try to use the same logic on a non-subroute, it works fine. How do I get the path of a named subroute?

```
router = mux.NewRouter() // this is a global variable
home := router.Path("/home").Subrouter()
home.Methods("GET").HandlerFunc(c.GetHomeHandler).Name("home")
home.Methods("POST").HandlerFunc(c.PostHomeHandler)

p, err := router.Get("home").URL()
if (err != nil) { panic (err) }
log.Printf(p.Path)
```

The above gives this error:

```
panic: mux: route doesn't have a host or path
```

Now if I do  `router.HandleFunc("/home", c.GetHomeHandler).Name("home")`, it works just fine.

Appreciate your help.

**Update:**

This is a reasonable workaround but it avoids creating a Subroute. It is fine for the example I had above but probably not ideal as you will not get all the benefits of a Subroute.

```
router.Path("/home").Methods("GET").HandlerFunc(c.GetHomeHandler).Name("home")
router.Path("/home").Methods("POST").HandlerFunc(c.PostHomeHandler)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'd need to specify your subroute with a PathPrefix, then in order to support /home and /home/ enable StrictSlash ([due to this issue](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/issues/31))

```
router := mux.NewRouter() 
home := router.PathPrefix("/home").Subrouter().StrictSlash(true)
home.Path("/").Methods("GET").HandlerFunc(GetHomeHandler).Name("home")
home.Path("/post/").Methods("POST").HandlerFunc(PostHomeHandler).Name("home-post")


p, err := router.Get("home").URL()
if (err != nil) { panic (err) }
log.Printf(p.Path)

p, err = home.Get("home-post").URL()
if (err != nil) { panic (err) }
log.Printf(p.Path)
```

Comment: Thanks @John. It looks like the API has changed as `home.Path` returns a `Route` type and it does not have `StrictSlash` method. I have updated my answer with a workaround but it does not use a Subroute.

Comment: The issue you were having was due to not using PathPrefix when defining the home Subrouter

Comment: Thanks, that works! You will have to add `StrictSlash(true)` at the end (your code does not have the input param `true`). Could you please update it when you get a chance so it will be fully functional?